# Is it possible to run Python's scikit-learn algorithms over Hadoop?

Tags: python, hadoop, machine-learning, bigdata, scikit-learn

I know it is possible to use python language over Hadoop.

But is it possible to use scikit-learn's machine learning algorithms on Hadoop ?

If the answer is no, is there some machine learning library for python and Hadoop ?

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **YES**. Because you can run almost everything on Hadoop.

Long answer: **it depends**. Answer to this question for a start:

- Can you split your dataset into partitions?

Also, you may find [this](https://speakerdeck.com/datasciencelondon/parallel-and-large-scale-machine-learning-with-scikit-learn) presentation useful (Hadoop is starting at 73'rd slide).

Comment: ok so if I understand, we are obliged to write our own map/reudce code. There is not some High Level library to directly call machine learning algorithms for hadoop in python, right ?

Comment: No, you can't write some general code in python and then magically transform it into scalable MapReduce job. There is no such technology for sure.

Comment: @shanks_roux just found it today and thought you might be interested. **[MLlib](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/mllib/)** is a part of Apache Spark project, It allows you to develop **Machine Learning** algorithms in **Python** (lib interoperates with NumPy) and run them on **Hadoop** (or without it). Give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

Look out for `jpype` module. By using `jpype` you can run Mahout Algorithms and you will be writing code in Python. However I feel this won't be the best of solution. If you really want massive scalability than go with Mahout directly. I practice, do POC's, solve toy problems using scikit-learn, however when I need to do massive big data clustering and so on than I go Mahout.